# explanation needed for tcl file

Tags: networking, tcl, ns2

I am new to NS2. I am creating a tcl file. Can anyone explain me the meaning of the following lines?

```
set udp_(0) [new Agent/UDP] 
$ns_ attach-agent $node_(1) $udp_(0) 
set null_(0) [new Agent/Null] 
$ns_ attach-agent $node_(2) $null_(0)
set cbr_(0) [new Application/Traffic/CBR]
$cbr_(0) set packetSize_ 512
$cbr_(0) set interval_ 4.0
$cbr_(0) set random_ 1
$cbr_(0) set maxpkts_ 10000
$cbr_(0) attach-agent $udp_(0)
$ns_ connect $udp_(0) $null_(0)
$ns_ at 2.5568388786897245 "$cbr_(0) start"
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What sort of explanation are you looking for?

Comment: i am tring to find out what has been done at each line @Donal Fellows

Answer (score 0):

Assuming ns_ was assigned similar to `set ns_ [new Simulator]` (you are not posting all the relevant code - e.g. what is node_(1)?)

In tcl `set varName value` assigns `value` to variable `varName`.
`[...]` is [Command substitution](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M11)

In your case it gives you handles to functionality of NS2
(e.g. `$cbr_(0) set ...` calls the set routine of an `Application/Traffic/CBR` object.

Roughly spoken: the scipt sets up a CBR over UDP connection...

Maybe this [Simple Simulation Example](http://nile.wpi.edu/NS/simple_ns.html) clarifys things a little. Otherwise you ought to read the documentation of NS2 ;-)